# jQuery auto load a div after a 5sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 4 div bars in my home page. I'm loading those div bars by on click. But I want to load the the 1st div when page loading, then the 2nd div should load after 5 seconds. after 5 sec 3rd div should load like wise. this is my code : -

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('#click1').click(function () {
        $('#desc1').toggle(400);
        $('#desc2').hide();
        $('#desc3').hide();
        $('#desc4').hide();
        $('#desc5').hide();
     });
});
```

Thnx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var delay=5000;

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#desc1').toggle(function(){
                $('#desc2').toggle(delay,function(){
                    $('#desc3').toggle(delay,function(){
                        $('#desc4').toggle(delay,function(){
                            $('#desc5').toggle(delay,function(){
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Try this

Comment: you want on page load or on click?

Comment: it should be on page load,as per the question.

Comment: just take out the click :)

Comment: Appreciate, Is it possible to stop this loop after running once?

Comment: It will always run only once..Once DOM is loaded Completely

Answer (score 0):

You can show them with delay(ms);

```
$('#desc2').delay(5000).show();
$('#desc3').delay(10000).show();
$('#desc4').delay(15000).show();
$('#desc5').delay(20000).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider **setInterval();**, cleanest way to achieve that IMHO.

Something like:

```
$('#click1').click(function () {
    var nb = 1;
    var int = setInterval( function(){                      
        var el = $('#desc'+ nb);
        el.addClass('show');
        nb++;
        if( nb > 5) {
            clearInterval(int);
        }
    }, 400);
});
```

I copied that from an old project. Note that I use CSS to toggle the div.

Comment: what if I focus to another window in middle of animation?

Comment: The interval will go on. You want to stop it on focus to another window ? If so, edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('#click1').click(function () {
        $('#desc1').fadeIn(400);
        $('#desc2').delay(5000).fadeIn();
        $('#desc3').delay(10000).fadeIn();
        $('#desc4').delay(15000).fadeIn();
        $('#desc5').delay(20000).fadeIn();
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

(function(s){
      var i = 2, flag, url;

```
  function load(){

    if( i == 6){
      console.log("complete output!");
      clearTimeout(flag);
      return ;
    }

    //make something
    $(selector+i).load(ulr+"&index="+i, function(){
      i++;
      flag = setTimeout(load,5000);
    })

  }
  load();
})('desc');
```

toggle can complete display or hide , i would like to use load and setTimeout